# How to make Emacs 'man' work over Tramp?

Tags: unix, emacs, emacs24, manpage, tramp

I have a question regarding the use of <kbd>M-x man</kbd> in Emacs. I'm working with Tramp all the time and often the installed program base on the remote server differs significantly from my local setup. I see that invoking <kbd>M-x man</kbd> involves looking for the relevant manpages on the local machine. Is there a way to instruct it to use the environment on the other side of Tramp?

I know there's an Elisp variable `tramp-remote-process-environment` and I've tried adding an entry for `MANPATH` to it, but it doesn't seem to work (I'm afraid it's because I put it in the form `/usr/share/man` instead of `/scpc:user@host:/usr/share/man` but what I want is a generic solution to work on all remote hosts). Any ideas?

Comment: `woman-find-file` handles remote man pages, if given a full path. My answer [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20996/10625) shows a hack to get this working if you use eshell; you may be able to take some inspiration from it.

Answer (score 3):

From the `Man-start-calling` macro in `man.el`:

```lisp
(let (...
    (default-directory
      (if (and (file-directory-p default-directory)
               (not (find-file-name-handler default-directory
                                            'file-directory-p)))
          default-directory
        "/"))
```

That is, if there is a special file name handler for the current default directory, such as Tramp, it will use the root directory as the directory to start `man` from, and thus it will see man pages from the system that Emacs is running on.

There doesn't seem to be a way to disable this apart from changing `man.el`.  Note that this is a macro, so you need to reload the macro *and* all the functions that use the macro.

Comment: Thanks @legoscia, it's interesting though. I would think that it's only natural to expect Emacs to interact with remote manpages.

Comment: Wojciech Gac: I can also imagine it being highly confusing (albeit less so if the buffer name incorporated the hostname or tramp path), but it would certainly seem reasonable for it to be a configurable option so that people who want the behaviour can get it. I'd suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: FYI the above code now lives `Man-getpage-in-background` and is not in a macro, but commenting out that `default-directory` binding does *not* enable remote man pages.

Answer (score 0):

From docstring of command man would expect it's able to read remote pages:

An explicit filename can be given too.  Use -l if it might
otherwise look like a page name.

```
/my/file/name.1.gz
-l somefile.1
```

You may write a caller, which reads the environment and composes the needed argument.

Comment: Yeah, it will probably come down to this :).